# How do I reset a capacitor once I have a signal rise?

Tags: capacitor

Once the signal rises to a certain level, my capacitor starts getting charged.

Once the signal falls back down to that same level, my capacitor stops charging.

This way, I am using the voltage of my capacitor as an indication of how long the signal stays above that level. I call this time duration as "hump duration".

My problem is, I have a train of such pulses. That means, after the 1st hump comes the 2nd hump and so on. In order to also get the "hump duration" of my 2nd hump, I believe I will have to reset that capacitor.

So how can I reset my capacitor when my signal rises above a certain level (i.e., right before next hump comes)?

Comment: You would have to drain the capacitor. Like what a 555 timer chip does.

Comment: ...and you do that by creating a discharge path, for instance with a transistor and a resistor in parallel to the capacitor.

Comment: It *sounds* like you're working with a sample and hold circuit. You could easily short the cap to ground (or some other voltage reference) if you need to. However, I'm not so sure that this is actually necessary, depending on your desired application and circuitry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is called a "Time over Threshold" measurement that is very common in particle detection applications (for example in Nuclear Science).

The problem you are having is called "pileup" and, as you noted, a direct consequence of not resetting the capacitor.  You need to do what is called "baseline restoration".

One common solution is to add a discharge path as clabacchio suggested.  The stupid simple way to do that would be to put a resistor in parallel with the capacitor you are charging.  Then, the capacitor would discharge based on the RC time constant of the value of the resistor and capacitor you are using.

Doing this makes a brutal tradeoff though, and may not work.  Here's the tradeoff: on one hand you want a small RC time constant so you can have a faster train of pulses.  A small RC means the capacitor will bleed its charge quickly and be ready for another pulse.  On the other hand, you want a large RC time constant so the capacitor holds the peak long enough for you to record the measurement.

If the simple technique I described doesn't work, you can put a transistor switch across the capacitor.  Once you've made the measurement, you pulse this transistor and do a hard reset, clearing the capacitor.  This technique is a bit more complex (especially if you're not using a computer already to acquire the data) but can be effective.  If you're not using a capacitor you need to have a comparator.  One input will be the signal you're measuring and the other will be the threshold.  The output of this comparator can then be connected to the switch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a similar technique to control a pump which sends water through a solar array, in response to the sun being "out or in". Maybe part of my circuit might help you. In my case, my "hump" is the sun shining or not shining, and naturally I don't want the pump toggling on or off continually. So first I have an op-amp used as a comparator, and that feeds a second OP amp, set up as a classic integrator. That integrator, in turn, feeds a second comparator with much more hysteresis, which ultimately controls a motor.  Its not meant to be an exact measurement, but it gives me an idea for your situation. What if you use a comparator as in the LEFT OP amp, with a small hysteresis for stability. When the voltage rises above a certain level (set by the resistors or a pot), the output will switch low, and the capacitor will ramp high over time. But when the input goes below your threshold, the capacitor will very quickly ramp low and reset. By having a much faster discharge path for the capacitor than the charge path, we've created a kind of reset after each accumulation cycle. Provided the capacitor doesn't max out from too long a pulse duration, the PEAK voltage at the output will always be proportional to the time of the last pulse.

Granted, this is the opposite of what you requested... the reset is happening immediately after the time span is recorded, instead of immediately when the pulse starts. But note that reset is never totally instantaneous, so it might be argued that resetting AFTER the accumulation has less of a chance to corrupt your measurement with a reset time.

Next, to make this useful, you'd either have to be sampling that output and taking note of its highest sampled value each time the first OP Amp (comparator) switches high. Or you might be able to stay in the analog realm, depending on what you want to do next.

[image: Pulse accumulator with fast reset]